# Debezium MongoDB Connector fails with CosmosDB MongoDB API

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm using Kafka Connect with Debezium MongoDB Connector to export some data from a CosmoDB (MongoDB API).

My connector config is bellow:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: ingest-ledger-small-collections
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: edh
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
  config:
    tasks.max: 1
    mongodb.hosts: <host>
    mongodb.user: <username>
    mongodb.name: mongo
    mongodb.password: <password>
    mongodb.ssl.enabled: true
    capture.mode: change_streams_update_full
    snapshot.max.threads: 1
    transforms: unwrap
    transforms.unwrap.type: io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState
    transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones: false
    transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode: drop
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable: false
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter.schemas.enable: false
    publish.full.document.only: true
```

When I start the process snapshot is take and works well, however, after that it gives the error bellow and stops to work.

```
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Failed to find starting position 'Timestamp{value=0, seconds=0, inc=0}' in oplog
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.readOplog(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:189)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$streamChangesForReplicaSet$0(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:114)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ConnectionContext$MongoPrimary.execute(ConnectionContext.java:288)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.streamChangesForReplicaSet(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:113)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:94)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:51)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:166)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Someone have an ideia how to solve?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm looking to use the connector with Mongo API on Cosmos too. Is it possible?